# Android Emulator staying on the black android screen and not starting

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Having an issue withh my emulator(s). WHen i start it the emulator stays on the black page with the word "android". Doesnt change.
 Logcat reads:

```
 08-16 20:01:11.580      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.580      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.590      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
         08-16 20:01:11.600      415-415/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
         08-16 20:01:11.700      415-415/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 30% free 2864K/4088K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 103ms
         08-16 20:01:11.780      415-415/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 31% free 2860K/4088K, paused 9ms+4ms, total 78ms
         08-16 20:01:11.830      711-711/? I/installd﹕ installd firing up
         08-16 20:01:11.830      711-711/? E/cutils﹕ Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
         08-16 20:01:11.840      711-711/? E/installd﹕ Could not create directories; exiting.
         08-16 20:01:11.920      415-415/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 31% free 2860K/4088K, paused 24ms+22ms, total 133ms
         08-16 20:01:12.000      415-415/? I/dalvikvm﹕ System server process 713 has been created
         08-16 20:01:12.010      712-712/? E/keystore﹕ chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
         08-16 20:01:12.030      415-415/? I/Zygote﹕ Accepting command socket connections
         08-16 20:01:12.210      713-713/? I/SystemServer﹕ Entered the Android system server!
         08-16 20:01:12.220      713-713/? D/SensorService﹕ nuSensorService starting...
         08-16 20:01:12.230      713-713/? I/SensorService﹕ Goldfish 3-axis Accelerometer
         08-16 20:01:12.230      713-713/? I/SensorService﹕ Goldfish 3-axis Magnetic field sensor
         08-16 20:01:12.240      713-713/? I/SensorService﹕ Goldfish Orientation sensor
         08-16 20:01:12.240      713-713/? I/SensorService﹕ Goldfish Temperature sensor
         08-16 20:01:12.240      713-713/? I/SensorService﹕ Goldfish Proximity sensor
         08-16 20:01:12.250      713-713/? D/SensorService﹕ Max socket buffer size 131071
         08-16 20:01:12.260      713-726/? D/SensorService﹕ nuSensorService thread starting...
         08-16 20:01:12.270      713-713/? I/SystemServer﹕ Waiting for installd to be ready.
         08-16 20:01:12.270      713-713/? I/Installer﹕ connecting...
         08-16 20:01:12.280      713-727/? I/SystemServer﹕ Enabled StrictMode logging for WM Looper
         08-16 20:01:12.280      713-713/? I/Installer﹕ disconnecting...
         08-16 20:01:12.290      713-713/? E/Installer﹕ connection failed
         08-16 20:01:12.290      713-713/? I/SystemServer﹕ Power Manager
         08-16 20:01:12.300      713-713/? E/PowerManagerService-JNI﹕ Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
         08-16 20:01:12.310      713-713/? I/SystemServer﹕ Activity Manager
         08-16 20:01:12.350      713-728/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Memory class: 64
         08-16 20:01:12.400      713-730/? W/BatteryStats﹕ Error writing battery statistics
      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/batterystats.bin.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.commitPendingDataToDisk(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5326)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$1.run(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5306)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.commitPendingDataToDisk(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5326)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$1.run(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5306)
           08-16 20:01:12.430      713-728/? W/UsageStats﹕ Error : java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) reading data from file:/data/system/usagestats/usage-20140816
           08-16 20:01:12.430      713-728/? I/AppOps﹕ No existing app ops /data/system/appops.xml; starting empty
           08-16 20:01:12.530      713-732/? I/UiThread﹕ Enabled StrictMode logging for UI thread
           08-16 20:01:12.560      713-713/? E/System﹕ ******************************************
           08-16 20:01:12.570      713-713/? E/System﹕ ************ Failure starting bootstrap service
          java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.readRulesDir(IntentFirewall.java:271)
            at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.(IntentFirewall.java:114)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.main(ActivityManagerService.java:1804)
            at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:196)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1179)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
           08-16 20:01:12.580      713-713/? I/SystemServer﹕ Display Manager
           08-16 20:01:12.600        45-76/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
           08-16 20:01:12.610      713-727/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab2ba8)
          08-16 20:01:12.610      713-727/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManager
          java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$LocalDisplayDevice.getDisplayDeviceInfoLocked(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:147)
            at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAddedLocked(DisplayManagerService.java:852)
            at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAdded(DisplayManagerService.java:841)
            at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.access$1100(DisplayManagerService.java:96)
            at

```
  com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$DisplayAdapterListener.onDisplayDeviceEvent(DisplayManagerService.java:1281)
        at com.android.server.display.DisplayAdapter$1.run(DisplayAdapter.java:108)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

 Whats the issue please?
```